# facebook android fast integration in our application

Tags: android, facebook, integration

Dude What is best and fast way to integrate facebook in android applicaiton and use it according to our requirement .

1. Get Friend's Basic information(`Like Phone number ,Email Address,Name,Age`).
2. List then in `List View`.

Dudes I read lots of article and official facebook documentation but found not fast to integrate facebook in my app.
i already read about the third party libraries named `easyfacebookandroidadk` (but here expected problem is stability of `api` ,which is not a trusted library as compared to face book grapg api).

any ideas ....

regards

Answer (score 1):

There is an official android sdk created by the facebook team. I suggest you use that one: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Don't forget to create an API key first.